# My entire monitor has zoomed in. And it zoomed everything in. Not just the google page but I mean everything became bigger

Tags: windows, windows-10

Does anyone know  a shortcut to fix this problem? I was mashing my keyboard as a joke and I think a hit a shortcut that makes everything on my screen bigger. The quality has seemed go down a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

You might have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scroll-Up (using the scroll button on the mouse).

What you could check:

- Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scroll-Down
- Go to Windows *Settings > System > Display* and look under "Scale and layout".
  Check both "Change the size of text, apps and other items" and "Display resolution"
- Right-click the desktop and in the View menu check the icons size.